# Why my keyPressed method stops reacting to any key i press after i hold (W/A/S/D) for 1 or 2 seconds?

Tags: java, jframe

```
public class Testing extends JPanel{

    public void Action() {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                if(move2==true) {
                    switch(direction2) {
                    case 1 : x-=2;
                    break;
                    case 2 : x+=2;
                    break; 
                    case 3 : y-=2;
                    break;
                    case 4 : y+=2;
                    }
                }
                repaint();
            }


        }, 10, 20);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {   
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 526, 690);
        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y-30);
        g.drawLine(x+1, y, x+1, y-30);
        g.drawLine(x-1, y, x-1, y-30);

    }
    static boolean move2 = false;
    static int x = 200;
    static int y = 100;
    static int direction2 = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    Testing t = new Testing();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(526,690);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setFocusable(true);
    f.add(t);
    t.Action();
    f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("did");
            switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                move2 = true;
                direction2 = 1;

                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:

                move2 = true;
                direction2 = 2;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:

                move2 = true;
                direction2 = 3;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:

                move2 = true;
                direction2 = 4;
                break;
            }

        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:move2 = false;
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:move2=false;
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:move2=false;
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:move2=false;
            }
        }
    });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not your code it is rather your Keyboard...

...most modern keyboards don't support enough key presses, aka as `N-Key-Rollover` (http://blog.controlspace.org/2010/08/n-key-rollover-what-it-is-and-how-to.html) so your event are 'swallowed'

***N-key rollover relates to the ability of a keyboard to correctly recognize multiple key presses at once (in the case, the ability to press as many keys as you want)...***

[image]